# How to get all Child Elements with specific attribute in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I have an object that was retrieved from this expression:

```
const element = document.querySelector("...my selector...");
```

I need to get all child elements that have certain attributes, The only way I know to get all children is by:

```
const children = Array.from(element.childNodes);
```

but now each `child` in `children` is not an [element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element), rather a [node](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node), hence, I cannot use `getAttribute('')` on them;

How do I "cast" a `Node` to an `Element`?, Or is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Have you tried `children`?

Comment: So use an CSS child selector with querySelectorAll??

Comment: So what is the actual HTML you are trying to select?

Comment: @epascarello, I am writing a simple robot(crawler) to retrieve some data. The actual data is in an `anchor` element

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> How do I "cast" a Node to an Element?

You can't.

Elements are a subset of Nodes.

If it isn't an Element already, then you can't turn it into one.

Consider:

```
<div>Hello, <strong>World</strong></div>
```

You have two child nodes. The text node `"Hello, "` and the strong element node.

It doesn't make sense to treat `"Hello, "` as an element.

---

Consider using [`children`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ParentNode/children) instead of `childNodes`. It fetches only **element** children.

---

> I need to get all child elements that have certain attributes

In that case, you're probably better off just using a selector which gets you that in the first place. You'll need a child combinator and an attribute selector in addition to your existing selector. Then you'll need to use `All` to get more than one result.:

```
document.querySelectorAll("...my selector... > [someAttribute]"
```

Answer (score 5):

You said you want to select all children with a specific attribute. So select them with querySelectorAll using an attribute selector.

```js
var elems = document.querySelectorAll("#theParentSelector > [theChildsAttribute]")
console.log(elems.length)
Array.from(elems).forEach( function (el) {
   console.log(el.getAttribute("theChildsAttribute"))
});
```

```html
<div id="theParentSelector">
  <div theChildsAttribute="1">Foo 1</div>
  <div>Bar</div>
  <div theChildsAttribute="2">Foo 2</div>
  <div theChildsAttribute="3">Foo 3</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

You'd use `children` to gain access to all HTML based nodes:

```
document.querySelector("...my selector...").children
```